# IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'E:\x07nu\meta.csv'

Tags: windows, python-2.7, backslash

IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'E:\x07nu\meta.csv'

```
f = open("E:\anu\meta.csv","r")


for line in file:

        x = line.split(",")

        print(x[0])
```

Comment: hii can anyone tell why this erroe is coming up this is a metadata file,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\a is creating problems. character like \a and \t etc create such problems.

Use a raw string instead:

```
test_file=open(r'E:\anu\meta.csv','r')
```

or double the slashes:

```
test_file=open('E:\\anu\meta.csv','r')
```

or use forward slashes instead:

```
test_file=open('E:/anu/meta.csv','r')
```

Comment: still not working ,giving error no such file or directory exists

Comment: then you should check the spelling, directory and the permissions.

Comment: i checked ,everything is correct , this is a metadata file ,maybe there should be some requirement of opening such kind of csv files

Comment: thank you for helping....... i got the my mistake ,the file format was not right..

Answer (score 1):

Try the following which does not interpret escape sequences of your path (like \a)

```
f = open(r"E:\anu\meta.csv","r")
```

Comment: now its giving eror:IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:\\anu\\meta.csv'

Comment: yes that file exists in E drive in a folder naming anu

Answer (score 0):

If using Python 2.7, open in binary mode **'rb'**.

Try using either of the below approaches:

```
f = open(r'E:\anu\meta.csv','rb') as f

f = open(r'E:\\anu\\meta.csv','rb') as f
```